# Windows Event Log: use EXE as EventMessageFileinstead of DLL

Tags: dll, exe, event-log

In the Windows Event Log, there are "Event Message Files" that contain templates for the logged messages.

The paths of the templates are stored in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog` and documented on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/EventLog/message-files.

According to the docs and most of the registry keys, the message files should be DLLs.  However, some of them seem to be EXEs.  e.g. `...\EventLog\Application\Wininit` lists an EXE for its EventMessageFile.  A few others do the same thing.

Can I use an EXE (e.g. the one that writes to the log) as a MessageFile as well?  Do I need to take any extra steps to make it usable?

Comment: The article skips a bit too fast over the reason you'd use LoadLibraryEx() instead of LoadLibrary().  Intention is to use LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE since only the resource string is interesting.  At which point it doesn't matter anymore that it is an EXE or a DLL.  Technically it is possible that some code you don't know about does it wrong.  Meh.

Comment: @HansPassant supposing everyone uses LoadLibraryEx correctly, how can I determine the symbol names to put in my EXE?  Do I have to make a DLL and look inside or is there a better way?

Comment: I just found an answer: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4166/%2FArticles%2F4166%2FUsing-MC-exe-message-resources-and-the-NT-event-lo

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash do post your answer here so that it would help those who come looking in the future.

Comment: @kowsikbabu do you mean I should post an answer instead of a comment?  I think since the answer is basically a redirect to another resource it doesn't matter

Comment: sometimes people coming to stackoverflow tend to notice that the question has no answers and fail to look at the comments, I think it'd be neat to explain the main logic(briefly) of the article in the answer and then post the link below for further reference, just a suggestion!